# Publishing PointCloud2

Tags: ros, pcl, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently using pcl under ros. i am trying to publish pointcloud2 which I have computed.
I already read tutorial from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)
But somehow I still have not get this right yet.

Let's say I call my computed pointcloud as cloud:
`pcl::PointCloud<Point>::Ptr cloud_aligned (new pcl::PointCloud<Point>);`

and here how I defined for publisher:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh3;
ros::Publisher pub = nh3.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("alignedcloud", 1);
ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
```

then here is how I try to call publish:

```
pub.publish(cloud_aligned);  
ros::spinOnce();
loop_rate.sleep();
```

Could someone give me some hints?

Best,
kang

some errors:

```
/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: 'const class pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>' has no member named '__getMD5Sum'
/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h: In static member function 'static const char* ros::message_traits::DataType<M>::value(const M&) [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]':

/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h:142: error: 'const class pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>' has no member named 'serializationLength'
/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h: In static member function 'static void ros::serialization::Serializer<T>::write(Stream&, typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type) [with Stream = ros::serialization::OStream, T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]':
/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:87:   instantiated from 'void ros::Publisher::publish(const boost::shared_ptr<X>&) const [with M = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>]'
/ros_diamondback/perception_pcl/pcl/src/tools/reg_icp_ros.cpp:88:   instantiated from here
/ros_diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_serialization/include/ros/serialization.h:124: error: 'const class pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>' has no member named 'serialize'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10389/publishing-pointcloud2/) by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are mixing two things.

You have a `PointCloud` and declared the publisher for a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`.

The best way is to use a publisher from [pcl_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros) (3.1) to directly publish a `PointCloud` as a `sensor_msgs::PointCloud2`. Alternatively you would have to convert that manually. The pcl_ros publisher will do this for you.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-07-20**:
There is no pcl::PointCloud2, only pcl::PointCloud. sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 is a generic structure that can hold any type of pcl::PointCloud (1 float, 30 doubles, whatever). pcl::PointClouds are specialized to whatever type you create them with (e.g. pcl::PointXYZ) and easier to work with in code.

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-07-20**:
Does this mean that pcl::PointCloud2 and sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 are not the same? Also, why so much namespace hell with either using pcl or pcl_ros?

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using the diamondback pcl, you probably need to include pcl_ros/point_cloud.h

You should take a look at the tutorials for pcl under ros: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-06-27**:
You're welcome. You should select an best answer by clicking the checkmark next to one of the answers.

**Comment by [kang](https://answers.ros.org/users/468/kang/) on 2011-06-27**:
Thanks, that was helpful.